# CSS y Script Editor

Tags: css, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

me encuentro con el siguiente problema:

tengo una barra de progreso a pasos (step progress bar), al interno del css incluye `:before` y `:after` funciona lo mas bien en html, lamentablemente cuando lo incorporo en el script editor, no me sigue las normas

este es el codigo, como pueden ver funciona perfectamente :

```css
.container-bar {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.progressbar {
    counter-reset: step;

}
.progressbar li {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    color: #888;
}
.progressbar li:before {
    color: #888;
    content: counter(step);
    counter-increment: step;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    border: 2px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
    background-color: #eee;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 2px white;
}
.progressbar li:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: #ddd;
    top: 15px;
    left: -50%;
    z-index: -1;
}
.progressbar li:first-child:after {
    content: none;
}
.progressbar li.active {
    color: #13e700;
}
.progressbar li.active:before {
    border-color: #13e700;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #13e700;
    content: "\2713 ";
    font-weight: 400;
}
.progressbar li.active + li:after{
    background-color: #13e700;
}
.progressbar li.waiting {
    color: #1d9eff;
}
.progressbar li.waiting:before {
    border-color: #1d9eff;
    background-color: #1d9eff;
    color: white;
}
.progressbar li.waiting + li:after {
    background-color: #1d9eff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-bar">
    <ul class="progressbar">
        <li class="active" id="1">
            step 1 
        </li>
        <li class="waiting" id="2">
            step 2
        </li>
        <li id="3">
            step 3
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

pero cuando lo meto al interno del scrip editor me pasa esto
[image: error dado]

como pueden ver me desaparece el `:after` y no me conecta los pasos, alguien sabria decirme porque ocurre esto y si hay alguna forma para hacerlo funcionar ?

Comment: Y si intentas desde el sharepoint designer agregar los archivos css a una ruta y luego la página que deseas agregas la referencia de los archivos? Al final termina siendo parecido a una págia html que si te funciona.

Comment: @AlonsoFallas he probado pero nada que hacer, al final solucione haciendo una ventana modal y creando un slider para visualizar las informaciones y los pasos, ya que a su vez el tooltip de bootstrap me lanzo un error y me bloqueaba todo el codigo js, gracias igualmente por el comentario

Comment: Bueno ni modo, al menos lograste resolver de alguna manera. Pura vida!